# append text on search input on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few anchor elements containing some text, something like "Cat", "Cow", "Dog".

When I click on "Cat" for example I want to append the text on the search input.

I've tried this:

```
jQuery(' .link ').on('click', function(event) {
jQuery('input[name="search"]').val(jQuery('.link').text().trim());
jQuery('input[name="search"]').keyup();

});
```

But I need a way to listen for each anchor element and update the search input accordingly, right now it works just once.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What should be the purpose of this line: `jQuery('input[name="search"]').keyup();`? Do you have an additional event handler bound to the search box's keyup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by your selector inside the click function, instead of adding the text of the clicked element to the search box, you are writing all elements' texts to the search box sequentially, thus only the last `.link` text remains in the search box. Try this instead:

```
jQuery(' .link ').on('click', function(event) {
  jQuery('input[name="search"]').val($(this).text().trim());
  jQuery('input[name="search"]').keyup();
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/osyusgaL/), see if that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided HTML so I'll take this(stackoverflow) page as example...

You can take text and add it to yours input property accordinglly: `document.getElementById('search').children[0].placeholder = document.getElementById('nav-tags').textContent;`

Practically, you should do something like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('search').children[0].placeholder = this.textContent;">Some animal</a>
```

Or, to make it more readable, create function and add event listener, but this is base...